# About oracle copying table structure

Tags: oracle9i

I need to know how to copy the table structure from another table without copping the data from another table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table where 1=0
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to do it.  But if you need the entire table definition, with things such as keys, check constraints, etc, you'll need to use DBMS_METADATA: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_metad2.htm#1024701